Custom List view column order name column after date column
I want to move name column after date column
I have try using this
listView : { columns: ['date', 'name', 'size', 'kind'], // Column visibility 
columnsCustomName: { date: 'Date', name: 'Name', size: 'Size', kind: 'Kind' } }

It show 2 column name, before and after date. how to move name column the right way?
